# after adding animation to the player's code in the play mode, he stopped moving

Tags: unity-game-engine

When creating the game, I came across the problem that after adding animation to the player's code in the play mode, he stopped moving.

I did everything as usual, went into the animator, made an animation, and then set up and added everything necessary to the code in the animator, but after that the player stopped moving although before that everything was fine.

Help me, I hope it's not difficult.

Here is the code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
[Header("Controlled player")]
public Rigidbody2D rb;

    [Header("Tinctures of movement")]
    public float PSpeed = 1f;
    public float jumpForce = 1f;


    
    [Header("Variable Reduction parameters")]
    public float LowingPSPeed;
    public float FormedPSpeed;
    

    [Header("Traffic Statuses")]
    public bool Move;
    public bool Jump;

    [Header("")]
[Header("Checking the ground under the player")]

    public bool OnGround;

    
    private bool doJump = false;
    private bool GOright = false;
    private bool GOleft = false;

    [Header("Ground Check Settings")]
private float groundRadius = 0.3f;
public Transform groundCheck;
    public LayerMask groundMask;


    private Animator anim;



    
    void Math()
    {
        FormedPSpeed = PSpeed / LowingPSPeed;
    }
    


    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        
        Math();
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            doJump = true;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            GOright = true;
        }else
        {
            GOright = false;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            GOleft = true;
        }
        else
        {
            GOleft = false;
        }
        
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        

        OnGround = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundRadius, groundMask);
        
        if (GOright && Move)
        {
            
            transform.position += new Vector3(FormedPSpeed, 0, 0);
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = false;
        }

        if (GOleft && Move)
        {
            
            transform.position += new Vector3(-(FormedPSpeed), 0, 0);
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = true;
        }

        if (doJump && Jump && OnGround)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, (jumpForce * 10)));
            
            anim.SetTrigger("takeOf");
            
            doJump = false;
        }
        

        
        if (OnGround)
        {
            anim.SetBool("isJump", false);
        }else
        {
            anim.SetBool("isJump", true);
        }

        
        if (!GOleft && !GOright)
        {
            anim.SetBool("isRun", false);
        }else
        {
            anim.SetBool("isRun", true);
        }
        
    }
```

I don't understand why this is happening

Comment: Do you have any warnings or errors in the console?

Comment: Probably your animation is hard coded, so when you move, your animation moves player back to the fixed position every frame. Create empty parent for your object which you will be moving, and move animation to the child and see if the problem persists.

Comment: No errors appear in the console. I'll try to do this

Comment: No, the problem still remains